# JDepend Maven Plugin - Add Excludes

Tags: java, maven, properties, jdepend

I want to use the the following mojo: [JDepend Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jdepend-maven-plugin/)

Unfortunately the generated report will also show dependencies to **java.*, sun.* etc.**

Now I have seen that one can specify a `jdepend.properties` file where [customization would happen](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html#customize). The thing is that I want to do this depending on the project. So I want to locate it somewhere in the project resources directory maybe, not in the user home directory.

Does someone know how this could work? How can I specify the path to my properties file?

And if this is not possible, how can I maybe exclude some classes in an other way?

Comment: Have you created the `jdepend.properties`. You can locate it in the `${project.basedir}`. The resources is not appropriate cause the property file neither something which should be packaged into the production jar nor is it only for testing. It is related to reporting. So a good choice would be `src/site` which is currently not support. Might be a good idea to improve JDepend-maven-plugin in that way.

Comment: @Vogel612: How would you do this with standard maven excludes? Is it possible? could you post an example?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I moved it to the `${project.basedir}`, the classes are still included in the report unfortunately. About the fact that the file should not be in `src/main/resources` you are right of course!

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Would you please so kind to file in a Bug at [JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJDEPEND)

Comment: @khmarbaise: Hi, sorry, I was on vacation and had no time to answer. I never submitted a bug on JIRA before, could you do quickly it maybe?

Comment: There is a [JIRA for that subject](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJDEPEND-3).